# How to read console response with python?

Tags: python, console, integrity, mks

My script creates issues in MKS Integrity (PTC)  -lifecycle manager- and after an issue is created the issue ID is only shown in console response (or in GUI, but that's not an option for me).

The way issues are made

```
im createissue …
os.system('im createissue ...') # in python
```

The response is something like:

```
Editing fields ...
Adding attachments ...
Field Attachments: Attachment attachment.something: added
Adding field values ...
Submitting ...
Created ISSUE_NAME ISSUE_ID
```

How would you store the ISSUE_ID to reuse for editing? 
Issue's State(workflow) has to be modified right after the issue was created (has to be closed).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `subprocess` module to obtain child process's stdout:

```
result = subprocess.check_output('im createissue ...', shell=True)
print result.split("Created ",1)[1]
```